# Does Firebase realtime database sync data changed while offline to the server even after app restart?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On firebases documentation it says:

> Even with persistence enabled, transactions are not persisted across
>   app restarts. So you cannot rely on transactions done offline being
>   committed to your Firebase Realtime Database. To provide the best user
>   experience, your app should show that a transaction has not been saved
>   into your Firebase Realtime Database yet, or make sure your app
>   remembers them manually and executes them again after an app restart.
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities

Yet I went into my App with an iphone 6 simulator, while offline, changed some data, then switched to iphone 7 simulator to make sure 6 simulator stopped, and then went back to the 6 simulator with my internet connection now turned on, and the change I had previously made while offline synced no problem.

What problem does this documentation point to that I need to take into account.  I can't afford to make something where users are frustrated with changes they thought saved getting lost, but to my eyes there is no issue?

Comment: As the doc says *transactions* are not persisted across app restarts, but other writes are. If you find that certain writes are persisted across app restarts, then you're very likely not using transactions for those writes. It will be a lot easier to help if you share the [minimal code that reproduces the behavior that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key word there is "Transactions" which are a very specific kind  of write operation. [(See description here)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

If you're just doing a regular ol' write to the database and not sticking it inside a transaction block, your write should be saved, even across an app restart.